# Discussion and Voting System for Company's Internal Code

Tags: programming, collaboration

Internally in my company, many teams has built common applications and packages that other teams are using. The problem is that it is not easy to decide new features to introduce to these applications/packages, or report bugs. I would like to have a method, similar to github's issue/bug/feature discussion.

The idea is for anyone to report bugs, or suggest a feature, and people can discuss it, vote for it, or reject it.

Is there an application that can handle that? We already have a git server, we are just missing the interaction part.

Comment: Did you have a look at Jira / Confluence etc. (https://www.atlassian.com/ ) (it are a commercial products, but I think there are some free usage cases as well).

Answer (score 2):

As you write "similar to github's issue/bug/feature discussion": Why not run your own Github? Quite easy that. I strongly recommend:

#### [Gitea](https://gitea.io/)

Like Github, this would give you e.g. an issue tracker and wiki, management of Pull Requests and more. Free and lightweight. Using it myself and am very satisfied with it. To give you some visuals:

[image: Gitea] [image: Gitea]
<sup>*Gitea:* Pull Requests, Listing repositories (source: [Github](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea); click images for larger variants)</sup>

More screenshots behind the Github link. There you also find downloads for all kind of operating systems. For each just a single binary which on updates you simply replace. Though "Gitea" is meant as "Git with a cup of tea", it could also stand for "Git made ea-sy"